# Wish to use Android colors (int) in OpenCV (Scalar)

Tags: android, opencv, colors

I wish to convert an Android color to an OpenCV Scalar

OpenCV requires this:

```
Scalar debugColor;
debugColor = new Scalar(0, 0, 255);
```

Android predefined colors are like this.

```
debugColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.RED);// <- mismatch
```

`R.color.RED` is defiled in the `res/values/color.xml in Android`

I want this cos intellij shows a color square in the code margin

[image: Sampleof how IntelliJ puts colors in its matgin]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would go like this:

```
new Scalar(Color.red(debugColor), Color.green(debugColor), Color.blue(debugColor));
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

Comment: I'm not sure about Java, but in C++ API are colors usually reversed: BGR, so it maybe need to be changed.

Comment: That is rather strange, I've never seen that in Java.

Comment: I would suggest also like to suggest the fourth Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0) option available.  If you use the three variable one and not the four variable constructure, the alpha channel seems to be set to something somewhat translucent.  This has thrown off the colors I was expecting.  I suggest providing the fourth as 255 to get full blown opaque colors as expected.